# How to deal with a ValueError and re-prompt the user a specific question in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

First-time poster and very new to Python and programming in general. I have been working on a character creator project and I'm trying to figure out how to deal with a non-integer being typed in for one of the attributes prompts, like "int(input('Strength: ')),"

I want to prevent a crash from the user typing in something other than an integer, and then to prompt the user to input the specific attribute again.

Here's a chunk of the code that I'm talking about.

```
class Char_presets:
    def __init__(self, name, type, strength, dexterity, wisdom, intelligence, faith):
        self.name = name
        self.type = type
        self.strength = strength
        self.dexterity = dexterity
        self.wisdom = wisdom
        self.intelligence = intelligence
        self.faith = faith

def create_clss():
    c1 = input('Save name?: ')

    c1 = Char_presets(
        input("What is your name?: "),
        input('Class type?: '),
        int(input('Strength: ')),
        int(input('Dexterity: ')),
        int(input('Wisdom: ')),
        int(input('Intelligence: ')),
        int(input('Faith: '))
    )
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Determine if the input string is an integer or not, and continue asking if not.

```
strength = input("Strength: ")

while not strength.isnumeric():
    strength = input("That's not an integer! Strength: ")

# at this point, strength will contain an integer
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the [walrus operator](https://realpython.com/python-walrus-operator/) introduced in python 3.9:

```
def create_clss():
    c1 = input('Save name?: ')
    while (strength := input('Strength: ')): # strength is defined here!
        if strength.isdigit(): # check if the input is all digits
            break
    c1 = Char_presets(
        input("What is your name?: "),
        input('Class type?: '),
        int(strength),
        int(input('Dexterity: ')),
        int(input('Wisdom: ')),
        int(input('Intelligence: ')),
        int(input('Faith: '))
    )
```

Of course, if you want to order in which the user inputs data to be kept, you'll need to store the rest of the input values in variables too:

```
def create_clss():
    c1 = input('Save name?: ')

    name = input("What is your name?: ")
    class_type = input('Class type?: ')
    while (strength := input('Strength: ')):
        if strength.isdigit():
            break
    dexterity = input('Dexterity: ')
    wisdom = input('Wisdom: ')
    intelligence = input('Intelligence: ')
    faith = input('Faith: ')
    c1 = Char_presets(
        name,
        class_type,
        int(strength),
        int(dexterity),
        int(wisdom),
        int(intelligence),
        int(faith)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `try…except` block inside of a `while` loop.
`try` block first executes and then if there is any `Exception` in the `try` block, it immediately stops the execution of the `try` block and goes to the `except` block.

[Python Exception Handling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)
Sample code:

```py
while True:
    try:  #Executes the block of code under it, and if an Exception occurs, it immediately jumps to the except block
        strength = int(input('Strength: '));
        break;
    except ValueError:  #Here we are 'catching' the Exception and giving our own commands when the specified Exception occurs
        print("Enter integer only!");
```